# Collapse Panel remain open which click and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel div which is collapsing able after clicking an arrow in that panel heading,

in that panel dive there are buttons active and deactivate which refresh the page
and after refresh, the panel get closed

I want solution with maybe js when someone clicks on activate and deactivate on that panel div buttons and after page refresh, because of that panel buttons the panel remain open at that time not close as 1st time when page loads

Code:    `<p data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" class="pull-right "> <span class="fa fa-angle-down rotate"> </span></p>`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Nothing , i am looking for a code which can do this function , and people said try this with js so i am looking for solution with js or PHP

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, not freecodeservice.com

Answer (score 0):

Store the "isOpen" variable in Local Storage and read it from there.
Read about it [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: I need solution with javascript , jqeury or PHP i dont think this is the right approach to this

Comment: That is a solution with Javascript. You only have two options when storing data and state (ie isOpen or isCollapsed) is data: Locally (on the user's computer) or on the Server (on your computer for each user).
Javascript = Local, PHP = Server.
Storing something like that on a server for each user is overkill and you waste time and resources sending the data and retrieving it every time it's changed.

Comment: Thank you very much , Let me try this i will let you know.